# So, I am on ubuntu and there is no wifi option in the top right corner

Tags: wireless, internet

I tried going to the network settings but it said that something is not compatible with the version that i am on or something like that. Please help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. Your question does not provide any way for us to help you. Please update us with all the relevant details, including, but not being limited to: what is your hardware configuration, are you able to connect through ethernet, what is the exact message that you mentioned, and where/under what conditions is it displayed etc? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check that if your wireless adapter is recognized properly or not ?

This command will list all the network cards in your computer. There should be one with Ethernet interface for normal LAN and other should be wireless interface

```
    # lshw -C network 
    *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

     *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

Once the adapter is there then you can try figuring out whether the drivers for that are installed correctly or not ? Once that is done, try restarting your machine.

After go into the network connections and try to add new network connections with wifi interface and wifi details.